# hadoop streaming error

Tags: hadoop, streaming

I have implemented a Naives Bayes classifier in shell script successfully, but when I try to run it as a mapper (hadoop streaming) for processing around 300,000 lines, I get the below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 254
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

The log has the same thing and does not contain any other extra debugging information.

Any suggestion? I have a hunch that it should be the memory constraint on hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Subprocess referred to here is most likely your shell script. 
The last command in it is most likely returning 254.